# Get all visible plain text and find out which HTML tag or DOM element each piece of text belongs to

Tags: puppeteer

I know how to get all visible plain text on a page:

`const text = await page.$eval('*', el => el.innerText);`

But I also need to know which element of the page each piece of text belongs to, and I can't find a way to do that.

Comment: How would you like the result to look?

Comment: @Aankhen: I really have no idea, I'm very new to Puppeteer as well as Javascript. Some way to iterate the structure of the document while being able to know which text is visible, and which item it belongs to? Essentially, I need to know which HTML tag the text is in, like header, title, hyperlink text etc.

Comment: Okay. Is Grant Miller’s answer insufficient?

Comment: @Aankhen: I haven't checked whether it parses everything on the page or just some subset of the items, but it does seem to work. If you have any other idea, approach or suggestion in mind, I'd appreciate your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client side, you can do this in a way that preserves order using [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Treewalker).  Here’s an example with sample content from [Web Scraper Testing Ground](http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/):

```js
const IGNORE = ["style", "script"];

const walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);

const pairs = [];

let node;

while ((node = walker.nextNode()) !== null) {
  const parent = node.parentNode.tagName;

  if (IGNORE.includes(parent)) {
    continue;
  }

  const value = node.nodeValue.trim();

  if (value.length === 0) {
    continue;
  }

  pairs.push([parent.toLowerCase(), value]);
}

console.log(pairs);
```

```html
<div id="topbar"></div>
  <a href="/" style="text-decoration: none">
      <div id="title">WEB SCRAPER TESTING GROUND</div>
      <div id="logo"></div>
  </a>
  <div id="content">
<h1>BLOCKS: Price List </h1>
<div id="caseinfo">In this test, the web scraper needs to scrape a price list organized in a block layout. Specifically, it has to:
 <ol>
  <li>Extract all the products (their names, descriptions and prices), while skipping advertisements</li>
  <li>Scrape discounted products only</li>
  <li>Scrape products with red prices only</li>
 </ol>
<p>
</p><p>There is a <b>ver</b> parameter (which varies from 1 to 5) to show different table versions (with different product numbers, best price and advertisement positions).</p>
<p>Also there are two tables presented:
 </p><ul>
  <li><b>Case 1</b> (simple one, with products and prices placed into the same block)
  </li><li><b>Case 2</b> (complicated one, with products and prices placed into separate blocks)</li>
 </ul>
<p></p>
<p>For testing, you may use the following sample links. The scraper should sufficiently scrape all data from a certain case using the same project:
</p><ul>
 <li><a href="/blocks?ver=1">Price list 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="/blocks?ver=2">Price list 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="/blocks?ver=3">Price list 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="/blocks?ver=4">Price list 4</a></li>
 <li><a href="/blocks?ver=5">Price list 5</a></li>
</ul>
<p></p>
</div>

<div id="case_blocks">

<h2>Case 1</h2>
<div id="case1">
<div class="prod2"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">Dell Latitude D610-1.73 Laptop Wireless Computer</div>2 GHz Intel Pentium M, 1 GB DDR2 SDRAM, 40 GB, Microsoft Windows XP Professional</span><span style="float: right">$239.95</span></div><div class="prod1"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">Samsung Chromebook (Wi-Fi, 11.6-Inch)</div>1.7 GHz, 2 GB DDR3 SDRAM, 16 GB, Chrome</span><span style="float: right" class="best">$249.00</span><span style="float: right;margin-right:10px" class="best">BEST<br>PRICE!</span></div><div class="ads">ADVERTISEMENT</div><div class="prod2"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">Apple MacBook Pro MD101LL/A 13.3-Inch Laptop (NEWEST VERSION)</div>2.5 GHz Intel Core i5, 4 GB DDR3 SDRAM, 500 GB Serial ATA, Mac OS X v10.7 Lion</span><span style="float: right">$1,099.99</span></div><div class="prod1"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">Acer Aspire AS5750Z-4835 15.6-Inch Laptop (Black)</div>2 GHz Pentium B940, 4 GB SDRAM, 500 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</span><span style="float: right" class="best">$385.72</span><span style="float: right;margin-right:10px" class="best">BEST<br>PRICE!</span></div><div class="ads">ADVERTISEMENT</div><div class="prod2"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">HP Pavilion g7-2010nr 17.3-Inch Laptop (Black)</div>2.3 GHz Core i3-2350M, 6 GB SDRAM, 640 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</span><span style="float: right">$549.99<div class="disc">discount 7%</div></span></div><div class="prod1"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">ASUS A53Z-AS61 15.6-Inch Laptop (Mocha)</div>1.4 GHz A-Series Quad-Core A6-3420M, 4 GB DIMM, 750 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</span><span style="float: right">$399.99</span></div></div>

<h2 style="margin-top: 50px">Case 2</h2>
<div id="case2">
<div class="left"><div class="prod2"><div class="name">Dell Latitude D610-1.73 Laptop Wireless Computer</div>2 GHz Intel Pentium M, 1 GB DDR2 SDRAM, 40 GB, Microsoft Windows XP Professional</div><div class="prod1"><div class="name">Samsung Chromebook (Wi-Fi, 11.6-Inch)</div>1.7 GHz, 2 GB DDR3 SDRAM, 16 GB, Chrome</div><div class="ads">ADVERTISEMENT</div><div class="prod2"><div class="name">Apple MacBook Pro MD101LL/A 13.3-Inch Laptop (NEWEST VERSION)</div>2.5 GHz Intel Core i5, 4 GB DDR3 SDRAM, 500 GB Serial ATA, Mac OS X v10.7 Lion</div><div class="prod1"><div class="name">Acer Aspire AS5750Z-4835 15.6-Inch Laptop (Black)</div>2 GHz Pentium B940, 4 GB SDRAM, 500 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</div></div><div class="right"><div class="price2">$239.95</div><div class="price1 best">$249.00</div><div class="ads"></div><div class="price2">$1,099.99</div><div class="price1 best">$385.72</div></div><div class="ads" style="clear: both">ADVERTISEMENT</div><div class="left"><div class="prod2"><div class="name">HP Pavilion g7-2010nr 17.3-Inch Laptop (Black)</div>2.3 GHz Core i3-2350M, 6 GB SDRAM, 640 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</div><div class="prod1"><div class="name">ASUS A53Z-AS61 15.6-Inch Laptop (Mocha)</div>1.4 GHz A-Series Quad-Core A6-3420M, 4 GB DIMM, 750 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</div></div><div class="right"><div class="price2">$549.99<div class="disc">discount 7%</div></div><div class="price1">$399.99</div></div></div>

</div>
<br><br><br>
  </div>
```

Use `evaluate` to call this in Puppeteer, per Grant Miller’s answer:

```
const pairs = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const IGNORE = ["style", "script"];
  const NONWHITESPACE_RE = /\S/;

  const result = document.evaluate(
    "//*[child::text()]",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  );

  const pairs = [];

  for (let i = 0, j = result.snapshotLength; i < j; i++) {
    const element = result.snapshotItem(i);

    if (IGNORE.includes(element.tagName.toLowerCase())) {
      continue;
    }

    const nodes = [...element.childNodes];

    for (const node of nodes) {
      if (node.nodeType !== document.TEXT_NODE) {
        continue;
      }

      if (node.nodeValue.search(NONWHITESPACE_RE) === -1) {
        continue;
      }

      pairs.push({
        tag: element.tagName.toLowerCase(),
        text: node.nodeValue.trim()
      });
    }
  }

  return pairs;
});

console.log(pairs);
```

---

Here is the original version of the client-side function, which uses XPath but always puts the direct children of a node before its indirect children:

```js
const IGNORE = ["style", "script"];
const NONWHITESPACE_RE = /\S/;

// get all text nodes in the document
const result = document.evaluate(
  // matches any node in the document that has at least one direct
  // text node child, including whitespace-only nodes
  "//*[child::text()]",
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
  null
);

// the result doesn't use the JavaScript iterator protocol, so we have
// to manually iterate over the elements
const pairs = [];

for (let i = 0, j = result.snapshotLength; i < j; i++) {
  const element = result.snapshotItem(i);

  if (IGNORE.includes(element.tagName.toLowerCase())) {
    continue;
  }

  const nodes = [...element.childNodes];

  for (const node of nodes) {
    if (node.nodeType !== document.TEXT_NODE) {
      continue;
    }

    // filter out whitespace-only nodes
    if (node.nodeValue.search(NONWHITESPACE_RE) === -1) {
      continue;
    }

    pairs.push({
      tag: element.tagName.toLowerCase(),
      // remove the `.trim()` to preserve leading & trailing whitespace
      text: node.nodeValue.trim()
    });
  }
}

console.log(pairs);
```

```html
        <div id="topbar"></div>
  <a href="/" style="text-decoration: none">
      <div id="title">WEB SCRAPER TESTING GROUND</div>
      <div id="logo"></div>
  </a>
  <div id="content">
<h1>BLOCKS: Price List </h1>
<div id="caseinfo">In this test, the web scraper needs to scrape a price list organized in a block layout. Specifically, it has to:
 <ol>
  <li>Extract all the products (their names, descriptions and prices), while skipping advertisements</li>
  <li>Scrape discounted products only</li>
  <li>Scrape products with red prices only</li>
 </ol>
<p>
</p><p>There is a <b>ver</b> parameter (which varies from 1 to 5) to show different table versions (with different product numbers, best price and advertisement positions).</p>
<p>Also there are two tables presented:
 </p><ul>
  <li><b>Case 1</b> (simple one, with products and prices placed into the same block)
  </li><li><b>Case 2</b> (complicated one, with products and prices placed into separate blocks)</li>
 </ul>
<p></p>
<p>For testing, you may use the following sample links. The scraper should sufficiently scrape all data from a certain case using the same project:
</p><ul>
 <li><a href="/blocks?ver=1">Price list 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="/blocks?ver=2">Price list 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="/blocks?ver=3">Price list 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="/blocks?ver=4">Price list 4</a></li>
 <li><a href="/blocks?ver=5">Price list 5</a></li>
</ul>
<p></p>
</div>

<div id="case_blocks">

<h2>Case 1</h2>
<div id="case1">
<div class="prod2"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">Dell Latitude D610-1.73 Laptop Wireless Computer</div>2 GHz Intel Pentium M, 1 GB DDR2 SDRAM, 40 GB, Microsoft Windows XP Professional</span><span style="float: right">$239.95</span></div><div class="prod1"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">Samsung Chromebook (Wi-Fi, 11.6-Inch)</div>1.7 GHz, 2 GB DDR3 SDRAM, 16 GB, Chrome</span><span style="float: right" class="best">$249.00</span><span style="float: right;margin-right:10px" class="best">BEST<br>PRICE!</span></div><div class="ads">ADVERTISEMENT</div><div class="prod2"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">Apple MacBook Pro MD101LL/A 13.3-Inch Laptop (NEWEST VERSION)</div>2.5 GHz Intel Core i5, 4 GB DDR3 SDRAM, 500 GB Serial ATA, Mac OS X v10.7 Lion</span><span style="float: right">$1,099.99</span></div><div class="prod1"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">Acer Aspire AS5750Z-4835 15.6-Inch Laptop (Black)</div>2 GHz Pentium B940, 4 GB SDRAM, 500 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</span><span style="float: right" class="best">$385.72</span><span style="float: right;margin-right:10px" class="best">BEST<br>PRICE!</span></div><div class="ads">ADVERTISEMENT</div><div class="prod2"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">HP Pavilion g7-2010nr 17.3-Inch Laptop (Black)</div>2.3 GHz Core i3-2350M, 6 GB SDRAM, 640 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</span><span style="float: right">$549.99<div class="disc">discount 7%</div></span></div><div class="prod1"><span style="float: left"><div class="name">ASUS A53Z-AS61 15.6-Inch Laptop (Mocha)</div>1.4 GHz A-Series Quad-Core A6-3420M, 4 GB DIMM, 750 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</span><span style="float: right">$399.99</span></div></div>

<h2 style="margin-top: 50px">Case 2</h2>
<div id="case2">
<div class="left"><div class="prod2"><div class="name">Dell Latitude D610-1.73 Laptop Wireless Computer</div>2 GHz Intel Pentium M, 1 GB DDR2 SDRAM, 40 GB, Microsoft Windows XP Professional</div><div class="prod1"><div class="name">Samsung Chromebook (Wi-Fi, 11.6-Inch)</div>1.7 GHz, 2 GB DDR3 SDRAM, 16 GB, Chrome</div><div class="ads">ADVERTISEMENT</div><div class="prod2"><div class="name">Apple MacBook Pro MD101LL/A 13.3-Inch Laptop (NEWEST VERSION)</div>2.5 GHz Intel Core i5, 4 GB DDR3 SDRAM, 500 GB Serial ATA, Mac OS X v10.7 Lion</div><div class="prod1"><div class="name">Acer Aspire AS5750Z-4835 15.6-Inch Laptop (Black)</div>2 GHz Pentium B940, 4 GB SDRAM, 500 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</div></div><div class="right"><div class="price2">$239.95</div><div class="price1 best">$249.00</div><div class="ads"></div><div class="price2">$1,099.99</div><div class="price1 best">$385.72</div></div><div class="ads" style="clear: both">ADVERTISEMENT</div><div class="left"><div class="prod2"><div class="name">HP Pavilion g7-2010nr 17.3-Inch Laptop (Black)</div>2.3 GHz Core i3-2350M, 6 GB SDRAM, 640 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</div><div class="prod1"><div class="name">ASUS A53Z-AS61 15.6-Inch Laptop (Mocha)</div>1.4 GHz A-Series Quad-Core A6-3420M, 4 GB DIMM, 750 GB, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit</div></div><div class="right"><div class="price2">$549.99<div class="disc">discount 7%</div></div><div class="price1">$399.99</div></div></div>

</div>
<br><br><br>
  </div>
```

Comment: I was extremely happy with your solution (thanks!), until I noticed that it can sometimes reorder items. Note how the "bold" text on [this page](https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/ChromiumCrawler/blob/master/index.html) is parsed after the text that follows it: https://travis-ci.org/VioletGiraffe/ChromiumCrawler/jobs/427650965
Can this be circumvented? Word ordering is extremely important in what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I was going to suggest the other answer but then I saw it has the same issue. I found a way to do it with TreeWalker. See the updated post.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, this works, the code is simpler, and it's at least twice faster than Xpath. I wonder how many more different HTML parsers JS has available out of the box :)

Comment: Haha. Excellent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution to obtain an array of objects that contain tag names with their associated text:

```js
const example = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return Array.from(document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'), e => [...e.childNodes].filter(e =>
       e.nodeType === 3
    && !['SCRIPT','STYLE'].includes(e.parentNode.tagName)
    && e.textContent.trim().length
  )).flat().map(e => ({
    tag_name: e.parentNode.tagName,
    text_content: e.textContent.trim(),
  }));
});

console.log(example[0].tag_name);     // DIV
console.log(example[0].text_content); // Hello, world!
```

Comment: From testing, it seems like this will include `script` elements and exclude elements that contain text alongside empty elements, e.g. `<p>Line 1<br>Line 2</p>`.

Comment: Is that a white list of all acceptable tags that you've added? (sorry if it's a silly question, I'm very new to JS).

Comment: Er, sorry, realized later that what I said was misleading… the issue isn’t just with `<p>Foo<br></p>` but rather any elements with mixed content (text & child elements together). See [the paragraph containing `ver` in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5voat26/), for example.

Comment: @Aankhen Good catch! Updated.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I have updated my answer, removing the list in question.