# Best way to pull all innerText from page into a json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, puppeteer

Im web scraping a series of simple html pages with puppeteer. I would like to pull all or most of the innerText of the html elements within the body and populate a json file with it in an organized manner.

There are a few variations of format to the pages. I am wondering if there is an approach that would lend itself well to pulling the text off a page and organizing it that doesn't depend as much on the format of the page.

I am pretty sure I can write the program to say if format 1 is the case, navigate like this, else if format 2 navigate like that and so on. However I am looking for a more elegant way to pull all of the innertext from the page into a json, and still be able to organize it by its elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend treeWalker to get all textNodes

I wrote an extension which does a similar thing for highlighting

https://github.com/asyncb/selection-highlighter/blob/master/highlighter.js

Comment: Thanks, this set me in the right direction! I found this searching around about treewalker and it was just what I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52275057/10235296